# Serial data transfer using Pyserial on FPGA Uart

Tags: python, pyserial, serial-communication

I know this has been discussed a lot but couldn't find the right solution to my problem. 
I am working on sending data into my Uart on an FPGA. 
The FPGA part is clear, I am using a 8 bit UART receiver\tx on the FPGA ide.
The data looks like 
000101010101
101010110110
101011001011
.
.
.
.
..
101010110110 ( i.e. 12 columns data and 4096 rows ASCII values)

Can someone help me with some way to send this data from pyserial into the Uart in binary form serially??
Thank you in advance..

Comment: You can convert data to binary with the package struct and then send them with pyserial

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can I send 12 bits at a time using pyserial?@scholi

Answer (score 1):

Old code I wrote when playing around with pyserial, might be of use:

```
class myser():
    timer = ''
    buffer = b''
    ser = ''
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def Cancel_Timer(self):
        try:
            self.timer.cancel()
        except Exception as ex:
            template = "ct: An exception of type {0} occured. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
            message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
            print(message)

    def OpenSerial(self, COM, Baud, Parity, sBits, dBits, Timeout):
        try:
            self.ser = Serial(port=COM, baudrate=Baud, parity=Parity,
                         stopbits=sBits, bytesize=dBits, timeout=Timeout)
        except Exception as ex:
            template = "op: An exception of type {0} occured. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
            message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
            print(message)

    def SendSerial(self, data):   
        try:
            if self.ser.is_open:
                s = str(data)
                chars = []
                for c in s:
                    chars.append(ord(c))
                    chars = list(map(int, chars))
                self.ser.write(chars)
                self.ser.flush() 
        except Exception as ex:
            template = "ss: An exception of type {0} occured. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
            message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
            print(message)

    def ReadSerial(self, tmr, period):
        try:
            if self.ser.inWaiting() > 0:
                __stb = self.ser.read(self.ser.inWaiting())
                self.buffer += __stb
        except Exception as ex:
            template = "rs: An exception of type {0} occured. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
            message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
            print(message)
        if not tmr:
            return
        self.timer = threading.Timer(period, self.ReadSerial, [ True, period])
        self.timer.start()
        return


mySer = myser()
mySer.OpenSerial('COM7', 19200, 'N', 1, 8, 0)
data = '010111010001'
mySer.SendSerial(data)
```